# Installation of Angular on Windows for multiple users

Tags: node.js, development, angular

We are setting up a server that will be used by all application developers for our organization.  One of the things I'm told we need, is nodejs, and then an Angular installation.  It seems that Angular is installed by and for each user (it's installed under C:\USERS<username>\AppData ...) and then installation folder(s) need(s) to be added to the PATH for each user.  And then to use the service, the user runs a command that starts a service/daemon listening on a port (4200 by default).

*Based on my understanding*, this seems all well and good for a developer who has his own machine. But once we get to the point where there are many developers using the system, it seems like a cumbersome setup (each user having to go through some installation) and problematic in that the first one to use the designated port (4200 by default) will surely be the winner and others will need to figure out a different port for themselves.  And then there's version maintenance and ... (ugh!) you get the idea.

I have searched and have not found guidelines for enterprise installation of Angular (and its prerequisits) in a multi-user environment.  Can you point me to some discussion of the topic, and/or provide guidelines that will get us started in a more enrprise-oriented mindset?

Thanks.

Comment: Start by giving every developer their own computer, on which they do the development. A central server setup like this is insane.

Comment: Gosh, @MichaelHampton tell us what you really think.  A little justification for that statement would have been helpful. I could likewise argue that it's insane to set up a different computer for each devloper.  (This sounds so 1980s...)  Let's try to develop an understanding rather than throw around insults.